# How to check the IP status in Yii2

Tags: php, url, yii2, ip

I have a web-service, which is deployed on a server. The `web-service` is working perfectly. Now I want to do is to deploy the same web-service on another server. And then at my client site I want to check that If any of the server is running than the call is made.

I want to do something like that

```
$Ip1= "192.168.1.1/GetSomeData";
$Ip2= "202.47.22.1/GetSomeDate";
```

Now I want to check the `Ip1` whether it is `running` or not

```
if(Ip1=="running")
{
     //call the web-service

}//if the Ip1 is not working
else if (Ip2=="running")
{
   //call the web-service

}
else
{
   //do nothing
}
```

How can i achieve that in Yii2?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If web-service is under your control you could make an echo method ans simply check if it echoes back an answer to you using normal web-service call.

On the other hand you could use curl to check for an existing file or service on your web-server as in [this post](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/05/php-check-if-a-url-exists-with-curl/):

```
 function isRunning($url=NULL)  
 {  
    if($url == NULL) return false;  
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? true : false;
}
```

Of course then your code looks something like this:

```
if(isRunning(ipAddress1))
{
     //call the web-service

}//if the Ip1 is not working
else if (isRunning(ipAddress2))
{
   //call the web-service

}
else
{
   //do nothing
}
```

Where ipAddress is a file or path on that server. There are also a lot of other ways. You could use [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) if you have an open port, or use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)  to fetch ping result....
Hope my answer helped.